# Simplifying if statements for project

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm new to python and I need some help on this part of my project.
How can I simplify this?

```
 if x == 'C':
    if y == 1:
        z = 1
    if y == 2:
        z = 2
    if y == 3:
        z = 3
    if y == 4:
        z = 1
    if y == 5:
        z = 2
```

Comment: Looks like the dictionary datatype would work well for this. If you nest them, this whole tree could be simplified to `z = myspecialdictionary[x][y]`.

Comment: Or a match statement in Python 3.10+

Comment: you cant simplify it, but you could make it a dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: The dictionary solution looks quite good, if you really stay on an if structure you should use `elif` instead only `if`

Answer (score 6):

Using a `dict` as a switch statement:

```
switcher = {'C': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 2}, ...}

z = switcher[x][y]
```

Comment: please note: the program will crash (raise a `KeyError`) if the key is not found. you should consider using `switcher.get(x, {}).get(y, None)` instead

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the frequency of the resulting values, the condition can be set by the expression

```
if x == 'C' and 0 < y < 6:
    z = (y - 1) % 3 + 1
```

Comment: Provided this is not a dummy example, you have a valid point. It is more explicit to compute an easy value rather than maintaining a (large) list of mapping. +1

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can just use list:

```
C = [None,1,2,3,1,2]
if x == 'C':
    z=C[y]
```